# "Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator" when running SpatialFeaturePlot()

Tags: r

I've been applying the Seurat vignette - [Analysis, visualization, and integration of spatial datasets with Seurat](https://satijalab.org/seurat/articles/spatial_vignette.html) on the [Human Melanoma, IF Stained (FFPE)](https://www.10xgenomics.com/resources/datasets/human-melanoma-if-stained-ffpe-2-standard) dataset from 10x genomics.

I first "untar-ed" the "CytAssist_FFPE_Human_Skin_Melanoma_spatial.tar.gz" file from the 10x  link above, and then loaded the data using the code below -

```
melanoma <- Load10X_Spatial(data.dir="[insert directory]",
            filename="CytAssist_FFPE_Human_Skin_Melanoma_filtered_feature_bc_matrix.h5",
            assay="Spatial",
            slice="slice1",
            filter.matrix=TRUE,
            to.upper=TRUE)
```

I want to run a spatial feature plot, like the one below from the vignette -
[example spatial feature plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9kWn.jpg)

I ran this code for my dataset -

```
plot2 <- SpatialFeaturePlot(melanoma, features = "nFeature_Spatial")
```

However, I receive the error message "Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator."

I have been searching to see if there were any previous posts on the same issue. However, the most related posts are about attempting to do mathematical operations on numeric and character objects (e.g. 1 * "two"), which I don't see as directly relevant to my situation (I checked the columns of the data files from the "untar-ed" folder, and all columns containing numbers are coded as numeric or integer).

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

--

Here's the output for str(melanoma) - [Output Pt 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TC0QC.png) [Output Pt 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWBt2.png) [Ouput Pt 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3yNt.png).

--

Here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bbM6i5u9ejC-gu2yRR1jJwNUhzgxy6e2?usp=sharing) to the H5 file and "spatial" folder that are needed to run the code (I've also included an R file with the code). Both the H5 file and "spatial" folder need to be put in the same place (and the directory should be set to there).

Comment: Did you use `str(melanoma)` to check the column types - what is the output from that?

Comment: Yes, I just added the output to the post.

Comment: Hi nemch, welcome to SO. I think you could get better feedback if you can subset the data or make a smaller dataset that reproduces the issue from scratch so we can see the issue ourselves without dealing with all the links and such. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks, I just added a link to the files and the code. Let me know if there's anything else that is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also tried applying the Spatial Seurat tutorial to a 10x dataset and faced the same issue.

After comparing this dataset to the practice dataset provided by Seurat, I realized that the issue comes from the coordinates of the spatial image being characters instead of integers. So I manually changed all the formats of the values in the coordinates, and it worked for me.

The code I used was:

```
embryo@images[["slice1"]]@coordinates[["tissue"]] <- as.integer(embryo@images[["slice1"]]@coordinates[["tissue"]])
embryo@images[["slice1"]]@coordinates[["row"]] <- as.integer(embryo@images[["slice1"]]@coordinates[["row"]])
embryo@images[["slice1"]]@coordinates[["col"]] <- as.integer(embryo@images[["slice1"]]@coordinates[["col"]])
embryo@images[["slice1"]]@coordinates[["imagerow"]] <- as.integer(embryo@images[["slice1"]]@coordinates[["imagerow"]])
embryo@images[["slice1"]]@coordinates[["imagecol"]] <- as.integer(embryo@images[["slice1"]]@coordinates[["imagecol"]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I  don't know if this is relevant but it might help someone, I was getting the same error with this code:

```
data = read.table(file.choose(), header=FALSE ,sep =',')
data[1] = data[1] * 5
```

and the correct way to call it is:

```
y = as.numeric(data$V1) * 5
```

where V1 is the name of the column/header, make sure that your data is numerical and not a string